# Test class not covering using currency Type on ManageCurrencyConversion

Tags: trigger, unit-test

This is my trigger for manage currency on campaign. I want to write test class for it but its not working showing 0% coverage because I am not able to insert currency type. Please help me to fix out this problem.

**Trigger :**

```
trigger ManageCurrencyConversiononCampaign on Campaign (before update) {

    list<CurrencyType> c = [SELECT ISOCode, ConversionRate FROM CurrencyType WHERE IsActive=TRUE AND IsCorporate = False];
    if(trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Campaign cmp : Trigger.new)
        {
            for(integer i = 0; i< c.size(); i++)
            {
                Campaign oldcamp = Trigger.oldMap.get(cmp.id);

                Boolean oldcampIsWon = oldcamp.CurrencyIsoCode.equals('SGD');

                system.debug('cmp.CurrencyIsoCode1'+cmp.CurrencyIsoCode);
                if(cmp.CurrencyIsoCode == 'CNY')
                {
                    //Sales Information Section//
                    system.debug ('cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c1'+cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c);
                    system.debug('oldcampIsWon'+oldcampIsWon);
                    if(cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c = cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Upgrade_Gross_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Upgrade_Gross_Amount__c = cmp.Upgrade_Gross_Amount__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Original_Upsell_Cancellations_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Original_Upsell_Cancellations_Amount__c = cmp.Original_Upsell_Cancellations_Amount__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Upgrade_Cancellations_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Upgrade_Cancellations_Amount__c = cmp.Upgrade_Cancellations_Amount__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }


                    //Sales Information Section//

                    //Campaign Section//

                    system.debug('cmp.Commission__c--->'+cmp.Commission__c);

                    if(cmp.Commission__c != null){

                        cmp.Indirect_Cost_Commission__c = cmp.Commission__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                        system.debug('cmp.Indirect_Cost_Commission__c--->'+cmp.Indirect_Cost_Commission__c);
                    }

                    if(cmp.Average_Sales_Value__c != Null)
                    {
                        cmp.Average_Sales_Value_New__c = cmp.Average_Sales_Value__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Sales_Incentive__c != Null)
                    {
                        cmp.Indirect_Cost_Sales_Incentive__c = cmp.Sales_Incentive__c * c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }

                    //Campaign Section//

                }   
                system.debug('cmp.CurrencyIsoCode2'+cmp.CurrencyIsoCode);
                system.debug('oldcampIsWon--->'+oldcampIsWon);
                if(cmp.CurrencyIsoCode == 'SGD' && !oldcampIsWon)
                {

                    //Sales Information Section//
                    system.debug ('cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c2'+cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c);
                    if(cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c = cmp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c/c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Upgrade_Gross_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Upgrade_Gross_Amount__c = cmp.Upgrade_Gross_Amount__c/c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Original_Upsell_Cancellations_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Original_Upsell_Cancellations_Amount__c = cmp.Original_Upsell_Cancellations_Amount__c/c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }
                    if(cmp.Upgrade_Cancellations_Amount__c != Null){
                        cmp.Upgrade_Cancellations_Amount__c = cmp.Upgrade_Cancellations_Amount__c/c[i].ConversionRate;
                    }

                    //Sales Information Section//

                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class :**

```
/**
 * This class contains unit tests for validating the behavior of Apex classes
 * and triggers.
 *
 * Unit tests are class methods that verify whether a particular piece
 * of code is working properly. Unit test methods take no arguments,
 * commit no data to the database, and are flagged with the testMethod
 * keyword in the method definition.
 *
 * All test methods in an organization are executed whenever Apex code is deployed
 * to a production organization to confirm correctness, ensure code
 * coverage, and prevent regressions. All Apex classes are
 * required to have at least 75% code coverage in order to be deployed
 * to a production organization. In addition, all triggers must have some code coverage.
 * 
 * The @isTest class annotation indicates this class only contains test
 * methods. Classes defined with the @isTest annotation do not count against
 * the organization size limit for all Apex scripts.
 *
 * See the Apex Language Reference for more information about Testing and Code Coverage.
 */
@isTest
private class TestManageCurrencyConversionCampaign {

    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

        CurrencyType[] curr= new CurrencyType();
        curr.ConversionRate=4.500000;
        curr.IsoCode='SGD';
        curr.IsActive=true;
        curr.IsCorporate=false;
        insert curr;

        Campaign camp=new Campaign();
        camp.CurrencyIsoCode='CNY';
        camp.Name='test';
        camp.Country__c='India';
        camp.Type='EDM';
        camp.Database_name__c='50+ Expo';
        camp.Original_Upsell_Gross_Amount__c=10;
        insert camp;
        // TO DO: implement unit test
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Neha

Comment: event is `before update` you need to perform update DML in test class `update camp` then only trigger will be fire

Comment: You don't need the `if(trigger.isUpdate)` clause because this is a `before update` trigger, so it will always be true

Comment: I would also get rid of the block comment at the start of the test class as it doesn't add much

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that `CurrencyType`is a setup object that can't be mocked using Apex DML. This is [covered in the sObjects That Don’t Support DML Operations documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm?search_text=apex%20dml%20objects)

Instead, query for an existing `CurrencyType` in your testmethod before creating your Campaign.  All of the org's CurrencyTypes will exist to the testmethod without mocking